# No puedo imprimir los datos de mi base en HTML- CGI PERL

Tags: perl, cgi

Necesito ayuda urgente, estoy haciendo este trabajo para la escuela y tengo que crear una tabla en html con los datos que extraigo de mi base pero no estoy encontrando la forma, es mi primera vez utilizando el CGI de perl y tengo muy poca experiencia. Busque en varios sitios de internet y en muchos tutoriales pero ninguno me sirvio de ayuda. Dejo el código, si necesitan el SQL se los paso. Por si es de utilidad saberlo, estoy utilizando un servidor local con Xampp

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI ':html';
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

my $cgi = new CGI;

print $cgi->header('text/html');
print $cgi->start_html(
    -head=>(
        $cgi->Link({'rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'href' => '../icon'}),
        -title => 'Hola mundo',
        -encoding => 'UTF-8',
        -meta => {
            'description' => 'Esta es la descripcion',
            'keywords' => 'keyword, keyword2',
            'language' => 'spanish',
            'robots' => 'All'
            

        },
    )
);

my $root = "root";
my $pass = "";
my $host = "localhost";
my $db = "Camiones";

#--- start sub-routine ------------------------------------------------
sub ConnectToMySql {
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    my ($db) = @_;
    
    # assign the values to your connection variable
    my $connectionInfo="dbi:mysql:$db;$host";
    
    # make connection to database
    my $l_connection = DBI->connect($connectionInfo,$root,$pass);
    
    # the value of this connection is returned by the sub-routine
    return $l_connection;
    
    }


my $mysql = ConnectToMySql($db);

my $consulta = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM login");
$consulta->execute();

my $row = $consulta->fetchrow_hashref();
my $us = $row->{'usuario'};
my $pa = $row->{'password'};
my $aidi = $row->{'id'};




print $cgi->table({'cellpadding' =>'10', 'border' => '1'},
    $cgi->Tr([
        $cgi->th(['Id','Usuario','Contraseña']),
        $cgi->td(["$aidi", "$us", "$pa"])

    ])
);
$mysql->disconnect();

print $cgi->end_html();
```

El resultado que busco es una tabla como la siguiente:

| id | usuario | contraseña |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | admin | admin |

Answer (score 0):

Si pones

```perl
use warnings;
```

al principio del código, te dará más pistas de qué es lo que puede estar pasando.

Yo sospecho que tiene que ver que el módulo CGI no está importando las funciones que generan el código HTML.

Prueba cambiando la línea de importación del módulo CGI por esta otra:

```perl
use CGI ':html';
```

Si se trata de un módulo CGI moderno tendrás la documentación de estas funciones en el módulo CGI::HTML::Functions. Verás que pone al principio que la recomendación moderna es usar otros módulos, como HTML::Tiny

Comment: Gracias, ya habia importado warnings. hice el cambio en la importacion de CGI pero no tuve muchos resultados, tambien resubi el codigo sacando un par de cosas que me quedaron sueltas. 
Con respecto a warnings, no se donde podría ver las advertencias que manda. Perdon por la ignorancia, mi experiencia es muy baja.

Comment: Las advertencias y mensajes de error suelen salir en el archivo error.log del servidor web. Y los errores fatales salen en la propia página web, por efecto del módulo CGI::Carp que tienes puesto.